# Apply global theme changes immediately

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I my WinRT app the user can sync their data with a server. Some of the data that is synced are global theme changes for the application.

I go about changing the global theme by dynamically creating a `XAML` file, then doing this.

```
var resource = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load( content );
```

I then overwrite the global themes for the app by doing this.

```
var resources = new ResourceDictionary();
var converters = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri( "ms-appx:/Resources/Converters.xaml" ) };
var callisto = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri( "ms-appx:/Resources/Callisto.xaml" ) };
var templates = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri( "ms-appx:/Resources/Templates.xaml" ) };

resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( converters );
resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( callisto );
resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( templates );
resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( resource );

App.Current.Resources = resources;
```

The resource file has this.

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeImageBrush" ImageSource="%%ThemeBackground%%" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

The `%%ThemeBackground%%` is replaced with the actual file location.

Some of the changes apply immediately, like the `NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle` style, but others do not, like an `ImageBrush`. The changes only show when the app is started again, and this code is ran during application launch in `App.xaml.cs`, instead of from a running page.

It this even possible?

Some notes on how this works.

- The code that sets the theme is in a separate class and can and is called from anywhere in the app.
- The `ImageBrush` is being applied to to this `<Border Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeImageBrush}"></Border>`.
- The theme changes do get applied to some things like `Style` changes to `NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle`.
- I've tried doing a `Style` change instead of the `Background` and that didn't work either.

**Update**

I also have a sort of "Master Page" setup with this. This is how it's created.

```
var currentFrame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
var masterPage = new MasterPage
{
    ContentFrame = currentFrame,
};
Window.Current.Content = masterPage;
```

The master page just contains the `TopAppBar`.

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <!-- buttons here -->
</Page.TopAppBar>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ContentFrame, ElementName=PageRoot}" />
</Grid>
```

The background image that isn't updating is applied like this on every page.

```
<Border Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeImageBrush}"></Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reload the page.

You can try this:

```
public bool Reload(object param = null)
{
    Type type = this.Frame.CurrentSourcePageType;
    if (this.Frame.BackStack.Any())
    {
        type = this.Frame.BackStack.Last().SourcePageType;
        param = this.Frame.BackStack.Last().Parameter;
    }
    try { return this.Frame.Navigate(type, param); }
    finally { this.Frame.BackStack.Remove(this.Frame.BackStack.Last()); }
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Should navigating reload things? This isn't working for me. I'm doing a sort of "Master Page", and maybe that's causing the problems. I put more details in the question on how I'm doing the master page.

Comment: I removed the master page and it still didn't work. I have to close the app and start it again for the background image to change.